# Downloading a file and saving it locally with PHP

Tags: php, url, zip, temporary-files

I need to save a zipped file from an external url and save it as a temp file for use.

I've been advised to look at tempnam() and sys_get_temp_dir(), however I'm unsure how (or where) to include the url for the external file.

Can anybody help point me in the right direction as to the right function to use (and how)? I know how to unzip the file, it's just where to include the external url that points to the zipped file etc.

Comment: so the question is how do i download a file from an external site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to load the remote file and [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save the content to a temp file.
You must have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled in your php.ini

```
file_put_contents(
    'path/to/tmp/file.ext',
    file_get_contents( 'http://url_of_the_file.com/download.zip' )
);
```

Comment: If you want to write to a temporary file you can just create a new file in your temporary directory using something like `$tmpfilepath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'someprefix');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("yoururlwithhttp/file.zip", 'r'));

The first argument is the file name that you want to save. If you want you can fetch it from the tmp folder or you can [rename](http://php.net/rename) it with php with current timestamp

Hope it helps